# Setting HyperLinkField to a Javascript Url

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, hyperlink

I have an issue where my Hyperlink field in Asp.net GridView is not accepting Javascript function that will open a popup dialog.

I am using the following snippet

```
 <asp:GridView>
     <asp:HyperLinkField
         DataTextField="SomeColumn" HeaderText="Some Column Text"
         SortExpression="SomeColumn"
         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:LaunchSomePopupdialog({0})"
         DataNavigateUrlFields="Id"
         ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" />  
 </asp:GridView>
```

However, when I use a page url, it works, e.g.:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/SomeOtherPage.aspx?Id={0}"
```

Is there a way I can make this work with my JavaScript function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to change it to a normal  tag inside of a template field without using the asp:hyperlinkfield.  Then you can do something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Some Column Text" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:LaunchYourStuff('<%#Eval("YourColumnID")%>')"><%#Eval("YourColumnDisplayText")%></a>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

All of your asp:hyperlinkfield attributes get placed on the templateField tag.

**EDIT**

You cannot place javascript in the hyperlinkfield, as this is [by design](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102300/asp-gridview-does-not-render-hyperlinkfield-when-a-colon-is-included-in-the-datanavigateurlformatstring)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a bound field and then change the text in the RowDataBound event. (This will allow EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks to work):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

Make sure HtmlEncode is false!

```
Protected Sub gv_RowDatabound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType <> DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim drv = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
    If drv Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("drv is nothing")
    End If
    Const detailsCol As Integer = 4
    e.Row.Cells(detailsCol).Text = String.Format("<a href='javascript:popUp(""Details.aspx?ID={0}"");'>Details</a>", drv("ID"))
End Sub
```